# Gradle sync failed : Cannot cast object 'main classesDirs' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection'

Tags: windows-10, build.gradle, gobblin

I am facing below while building gradle.
I am using gradle 6.5 and gobblin apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0 version.
I have added build.gradle file and idesSetup.gradle file.

D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0>gradle build --stacktrace
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

```
> Configure project :
Build property: gobblinFlavor=standard
Build property: jdkVersion=1.8
Build property: sonatypeArtifactRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/
Build property: sonatypeArtifactSnapshotRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
Build property: nexusArtifactRepository=https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2
Build property: nexusArtifactSnapshotRepository=https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots
Build property: doNotSignArtifacts=false
Build property: avroVersion=1.8.1
Build property: awsVersion=1.11.8
Build property: bytemanVersion=2.2.1
Build property: confluentVersion=2.0.1
Build property: hadoopVersion=2.3.0
Build property: hiveVersion=1.0.1
Build property: kafka08Version=0.8.2.2
Build property: kafka09Version=0.9.0.1
Build property: pegasusVersion=11.0.0
Build property: salesforceVersion=42.0.0
Detected Gradle version major=6 minor=5

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0\gradle\scripts\idesSetup.gradle' line: 33

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.java']
   > Cannot cast object 'main classesDirs' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection' to class 'java.io.File'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
        at 
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
 
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$1.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:183)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_asgsreuarus8fsv3k38ysektr.run(D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0\build.gradle:118)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
       org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:180)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.java']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addImperativePlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginContainer$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at jacoco_coveralls_support_e4f4lnoozsin33bmor3fkidu5$_run_closure2.doCall(D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0\gradle\scripts\jacoco-coveralls-support.gradle:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions.with(Actions.java:251)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$2$1.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$2.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:271)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.access$500(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:145)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl$1.create(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:260)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:251)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:256)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runProjectConfigureAction(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.access$400(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$1.doRunProjectConfigure(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$BlockConfigureBuildOperation.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runBlockConfigureAction(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.subprojects(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.subprojects(DefaultProject.java:1187)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
        at jacoco_coveralls_support_e4f4lnoozsin33bmor3fkidu5.run(D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0\gradle\scripts\jacoco-coveralls-support.gradle:31)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 148 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'main classesDirs' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection' to class 'java.io.File'
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.setProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:380)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.trySetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:181)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.trySetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.setProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:94)
        at idesSetup_9ue98th295tn3ja17gvrv7c0v$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3.doCall(D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0\gradle\scripts\idesSetup.gradle:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel.module(IdeaModel.java:90)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel_Decorated.module(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel_Decorated$module.call(Unknown Source)
        at idesSetup_9ue98th295tn3ja17gvrv7c0v$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(D:\Gobblin\Apache_Gobblin_0.14.0_Win_O\apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0\gradle\scripts\idesSetup.gradle:27)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionFilter$1.execute(CollectionFilter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:253)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.pluginAdded(DefaultPluginContainer.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$300(DefaultPluginManager.java:51)
         
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s





idesSetup.gradle :-

/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

apply plugin: 'idea'

subprojects {
  plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
    plugins.apply('idea')
    plugins.apply('eclipse')

    // Configure the IDEA plugin to (1) add the codegen as source dirs and (2) work around
    // an apparent bug in the plugin which doesn't set the outputDir/testOutputDir as documented
    idea.module {
      // Gradle docs claim the two settings below are the default, but
      // the actual defaults appear to be "out/production/$MODULE_NAME"
      // and "out/test/$MODULE_NAME". Changing it so IDEA and gradle share
      // the class output directory.

      outputDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
      testOutputDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs
    }

  }
}





Build.gradle :-


/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


apply from: 'gradle/scripts/environment.gradle'

buildscript {
  apply from: 'gradle/scripts/repositories.gradle'
  apply from: 'gradle/scripts/defaultBuildProperties.gradle'
  apply from: 'gradle/scripts/computeVersions.gradle'

  apply from: file('gradle/scripts/buildscript.gradle'), to: buildscript

  buildscript.repositories.addAll(project.repositories)

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.org.inferred:gradle-processors:3.3.0'
    classpath 'org.kt3k.gradle.plugin:coveralls-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.0.RELEASE'
    classpath 'me.champeau.gradle:jmh-gradle-plugin:0.4.4'
  }

  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.14.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"

downloadLicenses {
  includeProjectDependencies = true

  ext.apacheTwo = license('Apache License, Version 2.0', 'http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0')
  ext.bsd = license('BSD License', 'http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php')
  ext.bsd3 = license('BSD 3-clause', 'https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause')
  ext.cddlGplv2 = license('CDDL + GPLv2 with classpath exception', 'https://glassfish.dev.java.net/nonav/public/CDDL+GPL.html')
  ext.spl = license('SPL', 'http://opensource.org/licenses/SPL-1.0');
  ext.epl = license('Eclipse Public License - Version 1.0', 'https://opensource.org/licenses/EPL-1.0')

  licenses = [
      (group('com.linkedin.gobblin')) : apacheTwo,
      // https://zookeeper.apache.org/
      (group('org.apache.zookeeper')) : apacheTwo,
      // http://testng.org/doc/
      (group('org.testng:testng')) : apacheTwo,
      // https://db.apache.org/jdo/index.html
      (group('javax.jdo')) : apacheTwo,
      // Based on other javax licenses
      (group('javax.servlet.jsp')) : cddlGplv2,
      (group('javax.servlet')) : cddlGplv2,
      (group('javax.transaction')) : cddlGplv2,
      // http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
      (group('commons-beanutils')) : apacheTwo,
      // http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/
      (group('regexp')) : apacheTwo,
      // http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm/
      (group('asm')) : bsd,
      // https://github.com/codehaus/jettison/blob/master/pom.xml
      (group('org.codehaus.jettison')) : apacheTwo,
      // https://github.com/stephenc/jcip-annotations/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
      (group('net.jcip')) : apacheTwo,
      // https://github.com/google/re2j/blob/master/LICENSE
      (group('com.google.re2j')) : bsd3,
      // https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/issues/128
      (group('com.google.code.findbugs')) : bsd3,
      // http://www.beanshell.org/license.html
      (group('org.beanshell')) : spl,
      // http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/
      (group('c3p0')) : epl,
      'antlr-runtime-3.4.jar' : apacheTwo
      ]
  aliases = [
      (apacheTwo) : ['The Apache Software License, Version 2.0', 'Apache 2', 'Apache License Version 2.0',
                     'Apache License, Version 2.0', 'Apache License 2.0', 'Apache Version 2.0, January 2004',
                     license('Apache License', 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0')],
      (bsd) : ['BSD', license('New BSD License', 'http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php')]
  ]
  dependencyConfiguration = 'compile'
  excludeDependencies = [
      'gobblin-throttling-service-client-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-throttling-service-api-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-flow-config-service-client-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-rest-api-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-throttling-service-server-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-flow-config-service-server-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-rest-server-data-template-*.jar',
      'gobblin-flow-config-service-api-data-template-*.jar'
  ]
}

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/repositories.gradle'

apply plugin: 'org.inferred.processors'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/configureSubprojects.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/idesSetup.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/jacoco-coveralls-support.gradle'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/dependencyDefinitions.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/restli.gradle'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/testSetup.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/globalDependencies.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/javaPlugin.gradle'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/utilities.gradle'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/javadoc.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/sourcesJar.gradle'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/mavenPublishing.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/nexusPublishing.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/javaVersionCheck.gradle'

apply from: 'gradle/scripts/rat.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/scripts/release.gradle'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.13' }

/*
 * Hack for upgrading pegasus to version 11.0.0. For some reason, the gradle-plugins in
 * that version fails to bring in "tools.jar" into the classpath. The rest.li team is actively
 * seeking for a clean fix. This part will be removed later when the fix is ready
 */
allprojects {
  tasks.matching { it.name == 'generateRestModel' }.all {
    doFirst {
      it.codegenClasspath += files("${System.getProperty('java.home')}/../lib/tools.jar")
    }
  }
}

rat {
  excludes = [
    '**/.git/**',
    '**/.github/**',
    '**/.gradle/**',
    '**/.project',
    '**/.factorypath',
    '**/.settings/**',
    '**/.classpath',
    '**/*.iml',
    '**/*.iws',
    '**/*.ipr',
    '**/.rubyversion',
    'gradle/wrapper/**',
    'gradlew',
    '**/changes.md',
    '**/README.md',
    '**/.ruby-version',
    '**/.DS_Store/**',
    '**/.gitignore',
    '**/build/**',
    '**/target/**',
    '**/bin/**',
    '**/test-output/**',
    '**/Gemfile.lock',
    '**/*.tsv',
    '**/*.csv',
    '**/*.svg',
    '**/*.groovy',
    '**/*.yml',
    '**/*.properties',
    '**/*.conf',
    '**/*.xml',
    '**/*.md',
    '**/*.json',
    '**/*.avsc',
    '**/*.ddl',
    '**/*.dml',
    '**/*.txt',
    '**/*.pull',
    '**/*.job',
    '**/*.log',
    '**/*.sql',
    '**/*.zip',
    '**/*.gz',
    '**/*.tgz',
    '**/*.tar',
    '**/*.lck',
    '**/*.ctrl',
    '**/*.dat',
    '**/*.pem',
    '**/*.crc',
    '**/*.jst',
    '**/*.orc',
    '**/*.rc',
    '**/*.avro',
    '**/*.avro.*',
    '**/*.png',
    '**/*.jpg',
    '**/*.jpeg',
    '**/*.eot',
    '**/*.ttf',
    '**/*.woff',
    '**/*.woff2',
    '**/Dockerfile',
    '**/file*',
    '**/*.epf',
    '**/*.pdsc',
    '**/*.yml',
    '**/*.inc',
    '**/*.py',
    '**/*.gradle',
    '**/*.css',
    '**/*.sh',
    '**/*.avro',
    '**/*.txt.*',
    '**/*.key',
    '**/*.json.*',
    '**/*.template',
    '**/migrationConfig',
    '**/testTable',
    '**/encryption_provider_test_keystore',
    '**/default_dataset_urn',
    '**/metastore_db',
    '**/grok/**',
    '**/mock-couchbase/**',
    '**/mainGeneratedRest/**',
    '**/mainGeneratedDataTemplate/**',
    '**/gen-java/**',
    '**/META-INF/**',
    '**/package-list',
    '**/WebmasterPerformanceTuningMetrics',
    '.reviewboardrc',
    'CONTRIBUTORS',
    'RELEASE.md',
    'DISCLAIMER',
    'NOTICE',
    'LICENSE'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Gobblin doesn't build on Windows. Try to use Linux (WSL on Windows).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will be trying on Linux.

Comment: Hi S Das,
Could you please explain how have you done setup of apache gobblin in your system.
I am facing issue while setting up only.